# Interesting Information to Add to Answered Question

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966938/append-to-line-that-is-preceded-and-followed-by-empty-line)).  Several good answers to the question were proffered and my specific question was resolved.

However, I later discovered that, since I had asked the wrong question, I needed a different solution.  Luckily, my chosen answer to the above question provided enough clues that I was able to eventually compose a sed one-liner that solved my REAL problem.

I'd like to offer up my new one-liner in StackOverflow.  The question is, **how best to do this?**  I've several ideas:

1. Post a comment to my original question, or the chosen answer to said original question.  The problem with this approach is that the limited formatting capabilities commenting makes this option less than optimum.
2. Edit my original question, adding the additional developments under discussion here, to the bottom of said original question.
3. Ask a brand new "question" detailing the situation.  Perhaps the approach would be to detail the situation, then ask as to whether the subject new one-liner appears to be correct/robust.

My gut feeling is to go with option 3.

What think?

Comment: Why not just add another answer?  Or if the question is different enough, self-answer a new one?  Just make sure it's still up to the normal quality standards we have.

Comment: @davidism The question is different enough such that a new one is warranted.  Is it considered good form to self-answer a question?

Comment: Yes, that's encouraged.  Just make sure the question is still a good question that describes the problem and isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @davidism A self-answered question it will be!  Cheers!

Comment: Well, I tried to pose a self-answered question, but all it did was kick off a sh*tstorm.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073370/append-to-non-empty-line-that-doesnt-start-with-whitespace-and-is-followed-two).  So much for trying to do a good deed!